# App terminating Due to Memory pressure

Tags: ios, ios7

I am working on a project. I Run my project And found the Consumed memory is 27 MB only. App is using a camera. When I open up the Camera the app terminates. 
My app is terminating even the consumed memory is 27 MB only. What Should I do now. I am sorry If am asking simple question, am new this language and stackoverflow.  I searched Google and stackoverflow, I found some posts. Didn't find anything working for me.

Comment: Are you testing your app on iPhone4 or iPhone4S? Is app working fine on iOS6 or iPhone 5?

Comment: Can you show some code where you initialize your Camera ViewController?

Comment: could you show your code? It may related to coreGraphics method. post code if related to that?

Comment: How do you know that memory pressure cause the crash ?

Comment: If any of those objects use UIImage, then the memory is recorded elsewhere.  Watch some of the optimization videos from WWDC to learn more.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or the simulator? If it is the simulator then your app will definitely crash.

Comment: I think this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888366/ios-7-uiimagepicker-preview-black-screen/22000982#22000982